# Что должен знать начинающий веб разработчик?

Tags: apache, php

Доброго времени друзья. Учу веб технологии год) учу как попало, в разброс. Так как работаю в фирме админом сайта нужно знать всего понемногу. Но хочется уже как то становиться профессионалом и по порядку изучать самое главное. В интернете куча советчиков, но зачастую все словно кость собаке бросают. Толком не объясняют. В общем наткнулся на Хабре на данную статью [Что должен знать начинающий разработчик](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143392/)
Там в самом начале застопорился:

1. откуда и как браузер узнаёт IP адрес
       сервера
2. почему наш запрос будет обрабатывать
       apache
3. почему apache запустит PHP для
       обработки index.php
4. каким образом PHP обрабатывает
       скрипт index.php

Первый вопрос как бы понятен. Вбиваем доменное имя, идет обращение к ДНС серверу и собственно у него спрашиваем к какому IP адресу пренадлежит данный домен.
Остальные вопросы недогоняю саму суть) почему будет обрабатывать Апач? да потому что я так хочу ответить хочется) растолкуйте эти вопросы если кому не сложно. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. DNS
2. нипочему апач не единственный веб сервер, и вообще там много вариантов
3. тоже нипочему, только конкретная реализация, в которой используется апач, index.php объявлен возможным индексом и вместо mod-php использовали cgi (в случае mod-php апач просто  отправит в уже загруженный интерпретатор код из index.php)
4. Интерпретирует.

дурацкий какой-то опросник, если бы мне такую чушь на собеседовании выдали я бы гомерически рассмеялся и хлопнул дверью обозвав опрашивающего некомпетентным идиотом.

Comment: вообще лично мне интересно на собеседованиях не то чтобы человек правильно решил задачу (обычно я задаю задания которые может решить любой, кто хоть чуть чуть в теме) а то как он решит задание, т.к. это показывает не только уровень знания, но и привычки, сильные стороны. Т.е. для меня собеседование это не только вопрос принятия на работу но и определение ниши работника.

Comment: 3. в случае с апачем сработает правило DirectoryIndex index.php в конфигурационном файле хоста.

Comment: там же вопрос почему ? а еще это может быть `RewriteRule` и прочее и прочее.

Comment: Да, но у меня апач не стоит, так что правило DirectoryIndex не сработает так же как и htaccess :) Что делать? :))) Я уж молчу про 
`php -S localhost:8000` :)))  

ps; опросник действительно дурацкий

Answer (score 2):

html, php 5, sql (стандарт 2003год), java scripts (jquery), css 3. И как разворачивать веб сервер apach или nginx, для винды есть уже готовые сборки denwer и winginx

Comment: да не нужно вебдеву особенно кодеру знать как разворачивать апач. зачем оно ему в приличных местах ?

Comment: но будет очень не лишним :)

Comment: ну лишним не будет и умение пользоваться газосваркой а так-же управлять шагающим экскаватором :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Изначально, IP домена запрашивается у файла hosts (на вашем компьютере), если там не находит, запрашивает у DNS
2. У локального сервера есть свой выделенный IP( 127.0.0.1) и  если у вас установлен apache, он будет генерировать все ваши директории с папки home (по совместительству название домена) в файл hosts, и переадресует их на свой локальный IP( 127.0.0.1)
3. Потому что для работы с файлами «.php» нужен интерпретатор PHP, сами по себе они не работают, потому и называются серверными скриптами.
4. Сервер изначально относиться к файлам с названием index(.php/.html/…) как к приоритетному, по умолчанию, и открывает его как главную страницу, запрашиваемого пути url

Comment: 3ий пункт не совсем правильно. Апачу СКАЗАНО, что файлы с расширением .php обрабатывать PHP интерпретатором. 
4ый пукт вааще не правильно) Ввиду ТАКОЙ постановки вопроса, ответ будет как написал ув. @eicto :)

Comment: по первому пункту если углубляться, то там вообще интересно, порядок этого опроса в linux например обычно задается в файле /etc/nsswitch.conf т.е. можно там написать `dns files` и тогда сначала будет смотреть в dns а потом в /etc/hosts  а так-же там может быть nis и db ещё. Я молчу о том что можно подменить (зачем нибудь, например, для какой-то секурной надстройки) функцию gethostbyname с пом-ю preload :)

Comment: Ну и ладно ) Зато человек получил дополнительно важную информацию )

Answer (score 2):

Теория: Основы сетей и как работают протоколы. Знать зачем нужен DNS.

Из практики: .htaccess что он и с чем его едят. Уметь пользоватся локальными серверами типа Денвера. Разобрать пару CMS, можно начать с WordPress, MODx.
По языкам: PHP, Javascript + JQuery, HTML, CSS, MySQL.  - Это должны быть твои 5 заповедей новичка. Будешь знать эту пятерку без работы не останешься.

Comment: я вот никакой денвер не знаю :) наверное я лох с более чем 10ти летним опытом администрирования :)

Comment: Вы правы но в веб разработке это не нужно для новичка, вы говорите о Тьюринге, а человек еще HTML  в глаза не видел). Читать документацию само собой, куда же без нее... Ну и алгоритмы + логика...

Comment: так а какого... он в программировании делает, если он про Тьюринга не в курсе ? Вот именно сначала надо базу учить а потом всякие HTML/JS/CPP/php и прочие **инструменты**. А-то у вас получается что водопроводчик о воде не знает. Как он будет понимать в алгоритмах если у него кроме навыка ^C ^V нет ничего ?